# Calculating electrons emitted when quantum yield is given

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

In a problem, the wavelength $\lambda$ of a monochromatic light, power $P$ of the source, and work function $\phi$ of the metal on which the light is shown is given. Quantum yield is $n$. I have to find the rate of emission of electrons.

**My attempt:**

Energy in a single photon = $hc/\lambda$

Number of photons falling on metal per unit time = $\dfrac{P}{hc/\lambda}$

Quantum yield is the "number of times a specific event occurs per photon absorbed by the system." Then, the number of electrons ejected = $\dfrac{nP}{hc/\lambda}$

Is my approach here correct? I am mostly confused whether I've interpreted the meaning of "quantum yield" correctly.

Comment: Looks good: the quantum efficiency is between 0 and 1 and is generally wavelength dependent, so your n is for your particular wavelength.

Comment: Also do a dimensional analysis to convince yourself. Quantum yield of a process is "no. of particles emitted"/ "Number of particles absorbed".